# How to use the search module in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, module

First of all, I know that StackOverflow isn't a place for "how-to's". That said, my question is how to *effectively* use the [search module](https://www.playframework.com/modules/search) in any of my Play projects?

Is it possible (and a good idea) to use the search module on an `@Entity`?

Comment: Most probably you are using Play 2, while search module has disclaimer: _This module is for the Play 1.x series only._ they will not cooperate for 100%

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make powerful search, Elastic Search is the better choice, also there is Play module https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch to integrate with your application

Comment: Why? (meaning no offence)